# VCR runs only one time for integration test in capybara with selenium webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara-webkit, vcr

I am using Rspec with Capybara running the integrational tests using VCR gem to mock stub the api requests.
I am facing a vary weird kind of an issue. The test runs successfully for the first time and creates the yaml file for saving the requests and their responses.
But if I run test again after yaml file is created then it runs into an issue and shows the following issue :-

```
F

Failures:

  1) AffiliateSignUpProcesses Sign up using affiliate link should create User/Affiliate/AffiliateToken and Conversion when user is created
     Failure/Error: visit pricing_path(:aid => 'this_is_sample_value')
     VCR::Errors::UnhandledHTTPRequestError:


       ================================================================================
       An HTTP request has been made that VCR does not know how to handle:
         GET http://127.0.0.1:58021/__identify__

       VCR is currently using the following cassette:
         - /home/pcname/appname/selenium-error/fildername/appaname/cassettes/acceptanceTest/AffiliateSignUpProcess.yml
         - :record => :once
         - :match_requests_on => [:method, :uri]

       Under the current configuration VCR can not find a suitable HTTP interaction
       to replay and is prevented from recording new requests. There are a few ways
       you can deal with this:

         * If you're surprised VCR is raising this error
           and want insight about how VCR attempted to handle the request,
           you can use the debug_logger configuration option to log more details [1].
         * You can use the :new_episodes record mode to allow VCR to
           record this new request to the existing cassette [2].
         * If you want VCR to ignore this request (and others like it), you can
           set an `ignore_request` callback [3].
         * The current record mode (:once) does not allow new requests to be recorded
           to a previously recorded cassette. You can delete the cassette file and re-run
           your tests to allow the cassette to be recorded with this request [4].
         * The cassette contains 64 HTTP interactions that have not been
           played back. If your request is non-deterministic, you may need to
           change your :match_requests_on cassette option to be more lenient
           or use a custom request matcher to allow it to match [5].

       [1] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/debug-logging
       [2] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/record-modes/new-episodes
       [3] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/ignore-request
       [4] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/record-modes/once
       [5] https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/request-matching
       ================================================================================
     # ./spec/acceptance/affiliate_sign_up_processes_spec.rb:8:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/acceptance/affiliate_sign_up_processes_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.42 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

following is my vcr.rb :-

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
  c.hook_into :fakeweb
  c.cassette_library_dir     = 'cassettes'
end
```

And my integration test :-

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "AffiliateSignUpProcesses", :js => true  do
  describe "Sign up using affiliate link" do
    it "should create User/Affiliate/AffiliateToken and Conversion when user is created" do
      VCR.use_cassette("acceptanceTest/AffiliateSignUpProcess", :record => :once) do
        visit pricing_path(:aid => 'this_is_sample_value')
        @email="static_for_vcr@testdomain.com"
        #and other code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems like the capybara's "visit" is being treated as an external API call.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is considering all the localhost requests for "visit" as api calls.
So just need to fix them by ignoring "localhost" requests.
Simpley write the following in the vcr.rb file

```
c.ignore_localhost = true
```

Found it here :-
https://makandracards.com/ninjaconcept/tags/javascript?switch_to=pane

More exhaustive :-
https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-3-0/docs/configuration/ignore-request